# No sound from Java MIDI

Tags: java, javax.sound.midi

I am currently learning Java from the book Head First Java. I am trying this code as given in the book:

```
import javax.sound.midi.*;

public class MiniMiniMusicApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MiniMiniMusicApp mini = new MiniMiniMusicApp();
        mini.play();    
    }

    public void play() {
        try {
            Sequencer player = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            player.open();

            Sequence seq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 4);

            Track track = seq.createTrack();

            ShortMessage a = new ShortMessage();
            a.setMessage(144, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOn = new MidiEvent(a, 1);
            track.add(noteOn);

            ShortMessage b = new ShortMessage();
            b.setMessage(128, 1, 44, 100);
            MidiEvent noteOff = new MidiEvent(b, 16);
            track.add(noteOff);

            try {
                player.setSequence(seq);
                player.start();
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                player.close();
            } catch (InvalidMidiDataException ex) {
                System.out.println("Invalid MIDI data");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Can't play sound");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However I get neither any sound nor any error when I run this code. I am using openjdk 11.0.6 on Pop! OS 19.10. I am not able to figure out what might be wrong.

Comment: You need to install timidity and related tools to use MIDI (**unless** you happen to have a [MPU-401](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPU-401) or a clone **and** something like a [Sound Canvas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roland_Sound_Canvas) or other general MIDI device). Basically, MIDI is a professional audio standard for musicians and musical instruments. Without a lot of expensive hardware, you need to setup software emulation.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I haven't done any of that and the code runs just fine for me, as well as my previous efforts to mess around with MIDI. Java MIDI support is quite decent right out of the box. I would have guessed that policytool wasn't granting permission to play sound, but OP is on JDK 11+, which did away with applets and policytool. This is going to sound dumb, but... you can hear sounds via other apps, yes?

Comment: @MarsAtomic Yes I can hear sounds from other apps as well as I can play mid files.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I installed timidity, still didn't get sound

Comment: @MarsAtomic You're on Linux? Because OP is using Linux.

Comment: It worked after installing timidity and a reboot. @ElliottFrisch thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I used Ubuntu. After further research and some experimentation with hardware, it turns out my sound card was providing support via hardware.

Comment: @MarsAtomic Cool! Which sound card? And does it sound decent? Timidity, even with the largest sample packs I can find, doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It's an old SoundBlaster Audigy. I don't have what you would call a discerning ear, so I can only say it sounds OK to me. :-/

Comment: @MarsAtomic That's a decent card. I currently have a DAC connected to an ONKYO amp and hooked up via TOSlink. It far surpases my hearing discernment as well (except for MIDI).